# Windows 8.1 app : Identify UI text truncation for TextBlock with wrap, max lines or max height applied

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, desktop

I have a requirement to identify whether the text is getting truncated in UI programmatically with wrap applied, provided, the word trimming is not applied.

This is a 8.1 desktop app using xaml, c#.

This is a multinational app and the text is dynamic in length. Below is an example of `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource Title}" FontSize="34" Maxwidth="230" Margin="0,20,0,0" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap" Maxlines="3"/>
```

Comment: So, do you need to measure the Text to see whether it will overflow the bounds of the TextBlock?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: See the [FormattedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.formattedtext) Class.

Comment: hi. @Jimi This is only available for WPF application and this is windows 8.1 app. Not possible

Comment: Do you mean an UWP app? You know, `TextBlock`... See the [UIElement.Measure()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.measure) method. (e.g., `[TextBlock].Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));`. Then, instead of, for example, `GetPreferredSize()`, read the [TextBlock.DesiredSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.desiredsize).

Comment: hi @Jimi, this is not UWP. Its windows 8.1 app. I tried using Measure. It does update the UI. But how does it help in truncation identification for wrap enabled TextBlock? Can you clarify please

Comment: These methods give you the measure of the Text that a TextBlock will have, given the Text itself, the Font used, the control size and all other properties you have set. `DesiredSize` returns the final value. It doesn't update the UI. If you want to modify a control's size, use this measure yourself. Not sure about your platform. Is it `[windows-store-app]`? `[WinRT]`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i arrived at the answer with the help of above mentioned comments. Here are the steps:

1. Identify the height/width of the textblock with the above constraint applied.
2. Then remove the constraint and measure the height/width using `[TextBlock].Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));`
3. Compare the previous and current height/width. If the current Width/Height is greater than the constraint width/height, then the text is truncated.